# AttributeError when creating ZipFile

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, urllib, python-zipfile

#### Question

I get an `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'seek'` when attempting to create a `zipfile.ZipFile` from a file path.

I have no idea why, the traceback doesn't make any sense in relation to my code, is this a bug in the `zipfile` module, or did I not set something up properly?

I followed all documentation as best as I could, to no avail.

What is wrong with what I am doing, and is there a workaround / fix for it?

And could it also be a mistake I am making with `urllib` in any way, as in retrieving the file from the direct link?

#### Code

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from os import path
from zipfile import ZipFile

download_url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/obiqvrt4m53pmoz/tesseract-4.0.0-alpha.zip?dl=1"


def setup_program():
    zip_name = urlretrieve(download_url)

    zip_file = ZipFile(zip_name, "r")
    zip_file.extractall(path.abspath("__tesseract/"))
    zip_file.close()

setup_program()  # REMOVE after test
```

#### Traceback

```
$ python downloader.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "downloader.py", line 15, in <module>
    setup_program()
  File "downloader.py", line 11, in setup_program
    zip_file = ZipFile(zip_name, "r")
  File "C:\Python36\lib\zipfile.py", line 1100, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\zipfile.py", line 1163, in _RealGetContents
    endrec = _EndRecData(fp)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\zipfile.py", line 241, in _EndRecData
    fpin.seek(0, 2)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Thanks ahead of time, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlretrieve()` returns a tuple of the local filename and the headers. You should take the first item in that tuple and pass that to `ZipFile` instead of the tuple itself.

```
zip_name, _ = urlretrieve(download_url)
```

Comment: Thank you very much good sir! I must have skimmed over this when reading the docs. Accepted as the answer.

Comment: It might also be helpful to others if you would put this somewhere in your answer:
`zip_name, _ = urlretrieve(download_url)`