# zipped multiple excel files than merge its content into one file using python

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I am trying to create 2 functions with python

1. first function zip multiple excel files that exist in the given
   path.
2. second function read the content of the zip file than merge all
   existing file into one excel file.(all files has same structure.)

The problem is that when i run the script it crashs when it comes to read the zip file and display the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
            
import zipfile
import os
        
def get_all_file_path(directory):
    file_paths=[]
    for root,directories,files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root,filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)
    return file_paths
        
        
# Excel file merge function
def excel_file_merge(zip_file_name):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'r')
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, "r") as f:
         for file in f.namelist():
             xlfile = archive.open(file)
         if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
             # Add a note indicating the file name that this dataframe originates from
            df_xl = pd.read_excel(xlfile, engine='openpyxl')
            df_xl['Note'] = file
            # Appends content of each Excel file iteratively
            df = df.append(df_xl, ignore_index=True)
    return df
    
uploaded_file = 'F:/AIenv/test_zip'
file_paths = get_all_file_path(uploaded_file)
print("following files will be zipped: ")
for file_name in file_paths:
    print(file_name)
with zipfile.ZipFile("my _python_files.zip","w")as f:
     for file in file_paths:
         f.write(file)
f.close()
print("All Files Zipped successfully")
df = excel_file_merge(f)
print(df)
```

Comment: Does this help ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177085/python-zipfile-object-has-no-attribute-seek

Comment: @ShivamRoy i already saw this question and based on it i **closed the zip file** .

Comment: @Z4-tier where is the error in the formatting ?

Comment: sorry for the indentation error thank you