# how to merge multiple excel files using python?

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I have a code that zipped multiple excel files, and i would like to merge these files and to display their contents in one excel file. Do you have any new ideas how to write this function?

Also, where is the error in my functions?

When i run my code it crash and display the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute 'seek'
Traceback:
File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 131, in <module>
    excel_file_merge(f)
File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 77, in excel_file_merge
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'r')
File "c:\users\lt gm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1222, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
File "c:\users\lt gm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1285, in _RealGetContents
    endrec = _EndRecData(fp)
File "c:\users\lt gm\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib\zipfile.py", line 259, in _EndRecData
    fpin.seek(0, 2)
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import zipfile
import os


# Excel file merge function
def excel_file_merge(zip_file_name):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'r')
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, "r") as f:
        for file in f.namelist():
            xlfile = archive.open(file)
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            # Add a note indicating the file name that this dataframe originates from
            df_xl = pd.read_excel(xlfile, engine='openpyxl')
            df_xl['Note'] = file
            # Appends content of each Excel file iteratively
            df = df.append(df_xl, ignore_index=True)
    return df

# function in order to zipped files.
def get_all_file_path(directory):
    file_paths=[]
    for root,directories,files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root,filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)
    return file_paths
    
file_paths = get_all_file_path(uploaded_file)
print("following files will be zipped: ")
for file_name in file_paths:
    print(file_name)
with zipfile.ZipFile("my _python_files.zip","w")as f:
    for file in file_paths:
        f.write(file)
f.close()
print("All Files Zipped successfully")
excel_file_merge(f)
```

the error appear at this line  `archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'r')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - ZipFile' object has no attribute 'seek'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177085/python-zipfile-object-has-no-attribute-seek)

Comment: @jtlz2 NO I already close  zip file based on this post  but still the same error